# How to apply div inserted into another div to all elements with same class name

Tags: javascript, html, css, wordpress

I want to insert or wrap my second div into another new div container but it was not applying through all same class name. Please check and give my idea what is missing.

```
<div class="section" id="section1">
  <div id="myDIV"> --> I want to wrap this into a new div
   asdasd
  </div>
</div>

<div class="section" id="section1">
 <div id="myDIV">
  cbcvbcvb
 </div>
</div>

<script>
//org_html = document.getElementById("section1").innerHTML;
//new_html = "<div class='mydiv-container'>" + org_html + "</div>";
//document.getElementById("section1").innerHTML = new_html;

const parentObject = document.getElementById('section1').innerHTML;

[...parentObject].forEach((parent, i) => {
  //const childElement = document.createElement('div');
  const childElement = "<div class='slidesInner'>" + parentObject + </div>";
  document.getElementById("section1").innerHTML = childElement;

});
</script>
```

Result should be like this:

```
 <div class="section" id="section1">
  <div class="mydiv-container">
   <div id="myDIV">
    cbcvbcvb
   </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="section" id="section1">
 <div class="mydiv-container"> <-- this is not showing in the second section
  <div id="myDIV">
   cbcvbcvb
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't repeat IDs. You aren't selecting by class, you're selecting by ID and, as I said, these should be **unique** to each section.

Comment: so you mean, I will create code by #section1 then separate for #section2 with same class name inserted like mydiv-container?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First there is a typo here `"<div class='slidesInner'>" + parentObject + </div>";` . You can see closing `</div>"` has no opening quote `"`.

Secondly you need not to iterate over the content of `innerHTML`. Since innerHTML will give the content like `<div id="myDIV">asdasd</div>`. You can get this using `querySelectorAll` and use template literals to create a new wrapper div and set the innerHTML

```js
const parentObject = document.querySelectorAll('.section');
parentObject.forEach(function(item, index) {
  item.innerHTML = `<div class='slidesInner' id='subSection_${index}'>${item.innerHTML}</div>`;
})
```

```css
.slidesInner {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="section" id="section1">
  <div id="myDIV">
    asdasd
  </div>
</div>

<div class="section" id="section2">
  <div id="myDIV2">
    cbcvbcvb
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: sorry for the typo, your code give me loops for class="slidesInner" and it loops only in first section, I only want is the class="myDIV" would be same class in all sections that I want to add. like id=section1, id=section2, id=section3 the inner would be class=myDIV only not in number. appreciate your help. thank you

Comment: Hi, is there any you can make other way for this problem? help would be very appreciated. thank you